# Why does Vim think it is still running?

Tags: linux, vim

This is a follow up to this question: [Why doesn't vim always give me the option to delete a swap file?](https://superuser.com/questions/747662/why-doesnt-vim-always-give-me-the-option-to-delete-a-swap-file)

My laptop died with some Vim sessions open. These were all files I had already saved, so I don't need the swap files, but the "Delete" option isn't present when I edit some of them. As described in the question above, Vim thinks the previous process is still running:

```
Found a swap file by the name "~/.vim/tmp//%home%dominickpastore%research%codegen%rabbitmq.c.swp"
          owned by: dominickpastore   dated: Tue May 12 13:56:53 2020
         file name: ~dominickpastore/research/codegen/rabbitmq.c
          modified: no
         user name: dominickpastore   host name: carbon
        process ID: 8903 (still running)
While opening file "rabbitmq.c"
             dated: Tue May 12 13:56:49 2020
```

The thing is, my laptop was fully dead, so I know for a fact that the previous process is not still running! And just to be sure, I checked if there is another process with that PID, and there is not.

Interestingly, it only did this for 2 of 5 files I had open (all in different instances of Vim). It properly recognized the other 3 as gone.

How does Vim determine if the previous process is still running? Why is it sometimes mistaken?

Comment: Process IDs are continuously recycled, and especially on Linux, processes come and go, often very quickly; the fact that there's no such ID when _you_ looked does not mean that this also was the case when _Vim_ checked.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I can't *rule that out*, but this wasn't a one-off check. I checked several times while trying to figure it out. It never appears in `ps -f -p <pid>` and always shows as still running in Vim, until I delete the swapfile. I've even checked while the new Vim instance was still running in case the new instance happened to have the same PID.

Comment: It's possible that 8903 is now a thread of a process, rather than a PID. Vim uses `kill -0 8903` to check whether a process is alive (you can use that command line to see if your shell agrees.) See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/430428/281844) for an example of listing thread ids and napping them back to PIDs.